# What is this code do if( passedRecord == (recordptr)-1L ) passedRecord = 0L;

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am converting code from MS Visual C++ to C#.
What following code is doing

```
**if( passedRecord == (recordptr)-1L )
        passedRecord = 0L;**

typedef struct _desc {
    descprocsptr    pptr;       
    desctype        type;       
    size_t          size;
    int             id;
    void *          data;       
}   desc, *descptr;

typedef descptr listptr;
typedef listptr     recordptr;
recordptr passedRecord;
```

Answer (score 0):

**if( passedRecord == (recordptr)-1L )
        passedRecord = 0L;**

-1L is the value -1, but as a long. 
The if block tests if passedRecord is set to -1, and sets it to 0 if it is.

-1 probably isn't a valid memory address, so if the passedRecord is set to -1, it isn't pointing to anything. It was deliberatly set that way to show that it wasn't.

The normal way to show that a pointer isn't pointing to anything is to set it to NULL, which is usually zero. passedRecord might be -1 to show that it is the end of the list.

Unless there is a good reason not to, you'll probably want to convert this records stuff to use a Collection.